# Script as a hyperlink

Tags: html, powershell

I would like to put my script on a web page, when a user click the link, Script must execute.Not sure where to start with, Any guidance will be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You expect the script to execute on the client machine? That's not how browsers work.

Comment: `onclick="`<your JavaScript here>`"`. For example `<span onclick="RunTheScript();" >Click me!</span>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want users to click on a link and then execute a PowerShell script via browser it is possible with a workaround kind of way.

You have to keep the script in a SharedLocation (Like on a Server Drive and enable sharing of the folder. Suppose \ServerName\Location) and on the Webpage give a RunMe link to the shared location script (\ServerName\Location\Script.pse). If you wanna pass arguments then you need to create a shortcut in the properties set a target path with arguments. Give the link of shortcut on your website.

This is what we do in our environment. We mass mail the link of the script in a shared location.

Comment: Am trying to put in  powershell scrip. when the user click the link on webpage. wouldn't it launch the powershell at the background and request the input from the user ?

Comment: Make it accept arguments. You can create a shortcut which will automatically pass the arguments through the Target path. Then give the link to the shortcut. That way the script will just run in the background and then disappear.